# Maui Navigation

Tags: navigation, maui

How do I get notification that my class has been navigated to?
How do I get notification that my class have been navigated from?
Obviously, I have resources I'd like to allocate when my navigation moves to an object and I'd like to release those resources when the user hits the back arrow (or navigates further into the stack). What am I missing.

Comment: pages have `OnAppearing` and `OnDisappearing` events

Comment: I'm not navigating to Pages, I'm navigating to view models.

Comment: The 'stack' might have `Pushed` and `Popped` events?